# Error in sql syntax value ? but it's showing the value?

Tags: mysql, sql

the title isn't very specific but I don't know how to make it better. I've got this error in my sql telling me something is wrong but I don't understand why it's wrong, currently using mysql 8.0.24. If you wonder why it looks strange it's because I use it in lua

Sql:

```
local q = [[SELECT id, hex_id, steam_id, community_id, name, ip, rank FROM users WHERE hex_id = @id;]]
local v = {["id"] = hexId}
```

Error:

```
An error happens for query "SELECT id, hex_id, steam_id, community_id, name, ip, rank FROM users WHERE hex_id = ?; : ["steam:*****"]": ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users WHERE hex_id = 'steam:*****'' at line 1
```

Comment: I tested with and without must have copied the error from the one with the (). I've removed them from the error message

Comment: It's a string and saved as varchar(100) in the database

Comment: This is an image of the table structure https://prnt.sc/22avg3x

Comment: I was asking myself the same question

Comment: I have updated the error to the one where there are no () in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANK` is a keyword in MySQL 8. You need to enclose it inside backticks:

```
SELECT id, hex_id, steam_id, community_id, name, ip, `rank` FROM users ...
```

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to be working fine now. Didn't think of this